# Insert in Table2 is not exist in Table2 but in Table 1

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

table1 (TABLE_HRD_CONTACTS_V01)
`Col_Primary_Key,Col_Call,COL_EMAIL`

table2 (TABLE_EMAIL)
`Col_Primary_Key,Col_Call,COL_EMAIL`

Both have more.

The application adds to Table1.
My code is trying to insert in table2 exists in table1

This is code run to build the first time how is best way to insert going froward?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_EMAIL (`COL_PRIMARY_KEY`, `COL_CALL`, `COL_EMAIL`) 
SELECT `COL_PRIMARY_KEY`, `COL_CALL`, `COL_EMAIL` 
FROM TABLE_HRD_CONTACTS_V01 
WHERE `COL_PRIMARY_KEY` <> 999999999 ;
```

Comment: I tried for a long time to translate and understand what you wrote, but without success...

Comment: You can use a service like `https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT` to illustrate your problem. As of now, it is rather difficult to understand what you are trying to do and why it does not work as you expect.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to check for existence in another table is with an outer join (such as a `LEFT JOIN`) filtered down to only the rows that didn't match, like so:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_EMAIL (`COL_PRIMARY_KEY`, `COL_CALL`, `COL_EMAIL`) 
SELECT T1.`COL_PRIMARY_KEY`, T1.`COL_CALL`, T1.`COL_EMAIL` 
FROM TABLE_HRD_CONTACTS_V01 AS T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_EMAIL AS T2
    ON T1.COL_PRIMARY_KEY = T2.COL_PRIMARY_KEY
WHERE T1.`COL_PRIMARY_KEY` <> 999999999
    AND T2.COL_PRIMARY_KEY IS NULL; -- Didn't match a row in T2 so doesn't exist in T2 yet
```

Comment: Thanks, JD. That worked